# How can I prevent design being cut off in browser window?

Tags: css, overflow

When the browser is hiding some of the design (meaning scroll bars appear), the header and footer get sliced off. In other words, if the browser is narrower than the width of the "logo" and "footer_links" divs, then it cuts off the right side if the user scrolls horizontally to view the rest of the page. Seems that the issue stems from trying to position (relative or absolute) a div within either the header or footer.

Here's the CSS:

```
html,
body {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    height:100%;
}
#container {
   min-height:100%;
   position:relative;
}
#header {
    background:green;
    padding:0px;
    margin: 0;
    height: 100px;
}
#logo {
    position: relative;
    width: 900px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    left: 20px;
    background: yellow;
    height: 70px;
}
#body {
   padding:10px;
   padding-bottom:60px; 
}
#footer {
   position:absolute;
   bottom:0;
   width:100%;
   height:60px;   
   background: blue;
}
#footer_links {
    width: 900px;
    height: 60px;
    background: yellow;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Here's the HTML:

```
<div id="container"> 

<div id="header"> 
    <div id="logo">
    </div>
</div> 

<div id="body"> 
</div>

<div id="footer">
    <div id="footer_links"> 
    </div>
</div> 

</div>
```

I thought overflow: visible would solve the problem, but it didn't.  How can I avoid this issue?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Hey David, do you have a link to the website with this problem?

Comment: Are you asking if the visitor makes their browser window less than 900px wide (the width of the "logo"), how do you make the logo resize to fit in?

Comment: @Brian -- no link to a live website (I'm just developing it locally), but you can see that this website has a similar problem: https://www.hellofax.com/     In this case, as soon as a horizontal scroll bar appears as you resize the browser window to a more narrow width, if you then scroll horizontally the top and botton nav are cut off.

Comment: @Marcel -- if the visitor makes their browser window less than the width of the logo in the header, a horizontal scroll bar appears.  If you then scroll back to reveal the page, you'll see that it cuts off the yellow header.

Answer (score 6):

Here's a solution I just came across - apply a min-width to the body element.  So, if your site at a minimum is 960px across:

```
body {
  min-width: 960px;
}
```

This apparently works because a width of 100% would be the width of the browser, and if your content is wider than that, the background is still fixed to the width of the body.

Answer (score 0):

This should meet your needs

**The CSS :**

```
html,body { margin:0; padding:0; height:100%}
#container {min-height:100%;position:relative;}
#header { background:green;padding:0px; margin: 0; height: 100px;}
#logo { position: relative; width: 900px; margin: 0 auto;
        background: yellow; height: 70px;}
#body { padding:10px 0 60px; margin:0 auto;
        width:900px; background:red; /*add a height*/ }
#footer {margin:0;bottom:0;width:100%;height:60px;   background: blue;}
#footer_links {width: 900px;height: 60px;background: yellow;margin: 0 auto;}
```

**The HTML :**

```
<div id="container"> 
<div id="header"> 
<div id="logo"> </div>
</div> 
<div id="body"> </div>
<div id="footer">
<div id="footer_links"> </div>
</div> 
</div>
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks -- it seems though, that even with this solution, when you make the window smaller, if you then scroll back horizontally, you'll see the green area of the header cut off.  In other words, once your browser window becomes narrower than the width of the logo (in yellow), the rest of the header will get cut at the point of the browser window without extending 100% of the width.

Answer (score 0):

One option, if you know the height of `#header`, is to use an image the same color and height as `#header` and use it as a background image for `body`.

**Demo: [jsfiddle.net/DRF23](http://jsfiddle.net/Marcel/DRF23/)**

Comment: Thanks Marcel -- I tried that, but it's still not optimal, especially if you need a separate background image for body.

Comment: @David: The `html` element is available for a separate background in that case but I agree, it's not optimal unless `#header` is going to be a static height in which case it's the solution.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```
html, body {
    position:relative;
    overflow:hidden;
    margin:0 auto !important;
}
```